# I would like to make separate html files containing css and javascript * .html, * .js and * .css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function startTimer() {
  var newyr = new Date("January 1, 2019 00:00:00");
  var newyeartime = newyr.getTime();
  var todaytm = new Date();
  var todaytime = todaytm.getTime();
  var timeleft = newyeartime - todaytime;
  var leftdays = timeleft / 86400000;
  var lefthr = 23 - todaytm.getHours();
  var leftmin = 59 - todaytm.getMinutes();
  var leftsec = 59 - todaytm.getSeconds();
  if (Math.floor(leftdays) <= -1) {
    document.getElementById('scg-nyc-msg').innerHTML = "It's New Year Time, Friends!<br/>Happy New Year 2019";
    return;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('scg-clock-days').innerHTML = scgWrapChars(Math.floor(leftdays), -3);
    document.getElementById('scg-clock-hr').innerHTML = scgWrapChars(lefthr, -2);
    document.getElementById('scg-clock-mins').innerHTML = scgWrapChars(leftmin, -2);
    document.getElementById('scg-clock-secs').innerHTML = scgWrapChars(leftsec, -2);
  }
  setTimeout('startTimer()', 999);
}
startTimer();
document.getElementById('scg-nyc-wrapper');

function scgWrapChars(str, pad) {
  str = (Math.pow(10, Math.abs(pad)) + str.toString()).slice(pad);
  return str.replace(/\w/g, "<span>$&</span>");
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information. Please describe what your final goal is, how you tried to achieve it, and where you got stuck. Try to paste all relevant code and error messages you are facing. Like this nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: yes, please specify some things to start with , look : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So far I don't feel like there is any correlation between the code you added and your question.

Comment: This is CDNY.js and is not loaded into the CDNY.html file if I call <script src = "CDNY.js"> </ script>

Comment: How can I show you the full html, css and js files?

Comment: http://www.trzinka.si/CDNY/index.html

Comment: Excuse me, is there enough information right now?

Comment: If I give javascript code to html file it works.

Comment: http://www.trzinka.si/CDNY/index1.html

Comment: If it's all together. It works.

Comment: You should explain in the question body that you have an html page where all the code is embebed and works but when you include the code it doesn't. Then you should put the code of you page with error or a link with page.

Comment: So www.trzinka.si/CDNY/index.html is in conjunction with the external DCNY js and css file that only loads the style from the css file. I would also like to read js file whose code is the same as in trzinka.si/CDNY/index1.html. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I would also like to use the DCNY.js file on other pages. So when the new year passes, it will only repair the new date in DCNY.js

Comment: If you try to copy the javascript code from index1.html to DCNY.js and then call it index.htm, the js file is not loaded. The whole example is at www.trzinka.si

Comment: Oh my oh my.
It's working now. I added the below function to DCNY.js

window.onload = function ()
   startTimer ();
}

Thank you very much for your efforts! I am grateful to you forever.

Your Robert

Comment: The thing works. You can view it at:
http://www.trzinka.si/
Excuse me because it is in Slovenian.
Thanks to everyone again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the javascript is loaded and executed while the page loads and mounts. So the DOM objects you are trying to use don't yet exist.

What you have to do? You have to run this code right after the page loads. You can do this by adding onload event in body tag.

```
<head>
    <title>Odštevanje do Novega Leta</title>
</head>
<body onload="startTimer();">
```

Or you can do this way in javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
  startTimer();
}
```

**Tip:** To check if something is wrong with your code, use the browser inspector.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null